# Process Byte Triples python

Tags: python, arrays, bit

The input to this function are three bytes in a list. (B01 , B02 , B03) (124,102,235)
Take the second byte and split it in two
Take the first 4 Bits (least significant) and store them into a variable (B02a)
Store the last 4 Bits (most significant) into another variable (B02b).

Do u have some ideas for python?

i tried this

```
input_list= (120,198,235)
byte_list =bytearray(input_list)
middle_var=byte_list[1]

print(middle_var)
print(type(middle_var))
```

## remove last 4 characters

```
B02b = middle_var[:6] 
print(B02b)
```

## remove first 4 characters

```
B02a = middle_var[4:] 

but didnt worked
```

it should look like this.

(01111000 11000110 11101011)

```
     (**1100** *0110* ) these from the middle (396) split in 2 * 4 bits
```

(**1100**01111000  *0110*11101011)

and the result should be
12768 **1100**01111000 and  1771 *0110*11101011

Comment: see [Python Bitwise Operators Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm). It has nothing to do with array and slicing.

Comment: it could be (if you don't want to move bytes) something like `B02a = input_list[1] & 0x0F` and `B02b = input_list[1] & 0xF0`

Comment: hey furas, thank u for ur help! i tryied it and it worked but not great. finally it should look like this.

Comment: it seems you need also `(B02a<<4) + B01` and `(B02B<<8)  + B03`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bitewise operators

```
B01, B02, B03 = (120,198,235)

print(f' B01: {B01:012b}', B01)
print(f' B02: {B02:012b}', B02)
print(f' B03: {B03:012b}', B03)
print('---')

B02a = B02 & 0xF0
B02b = B02 & 0x0F

print(f'B02a: {B02a:012b}', B02a)
print(f'B02b: {B02b:012b}', B02b)
print('---')

B02a = B02a << 4
B02b = B02b << 8

print(f'B02a: {B02a:012b}', B02a)
print(f'B02b: {B02b:012b}', B02b)
print('---')

X1 = B01 | B02a
X2 = B03 | B02b

print(f'  X1: {X1:012b}', X1)
print(f'  X2: {X2:012b}', X2)
print('---')
```

Result:

```
 B01: 000001111000 120
 B02: 000011000110 198
 B03: 000011101011 235
---
B02a: 000011000000 192
B02b: 000000000110 6
---
B02a: 110000000000 3072
B02b: 011000000000 1536
---
  X1: 110001111000 3192
  X2: 011011101011 1771
```

Bits are as expected but you incorrectly convert `110001111000` to `12768` because it gives `3192`.

```
int('110001111000', 2) # 3192
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bit moving and "&" operator in order to calculate B02a and B02b. please change your code like this.

```
B02a = B02 & 15
B02b = B02 >> 4
```